# How to tell if all mocha tests pass via mocha object?

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I'd like to perform some action if all of the tests pass in mocha and a different action if even one test fails.

```
<div id="mocha"></div>
<div id="messages"></div>
<div id="fixtures"></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.1.0/mocha.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.1.0/mocha.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/1.10.0/chai.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/1.7.3/sinon-min.js"></script>
<script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
<script src="my_tests.js"></script>
<script>mocha.run();</script>
```

Is there anything on the mocha object that indicates completeness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/mocha.js#L410-L416

```
<script>
mocha.run(function(failure_count) { 
    var success = failure_count ? false : true;
    // ...
});
</script>
```